# Testing an Oracle DB connection before it is made - ERROR?

Tags: oracle

I tried to make a new oracle DB connection with user name and password. I entered the connection name, user name and password in the new connection window. When I click the "test" button or the "connect" button, I get the following error: 
Status : Failure - Test Failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Why am I getting this error ? What does the Test & Connect button actually do ?

Comment: Note- I found that one reason for this error is setting username = user. That's NOT allowed.

Comment: The error still remains.

Comment: You're talking about a test button in a program we could guess but it might be wrong and the answer, useless... where are you setting the connection? Also, the error is not being raised before making the connection because you're trying to connect to the DB and perform a select 1 from dual.

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling your user login username or password is incorrect. Remember that from 11g onwards, passwords are case sensitive.

The test & connect button tests if the entered details (TNSName, port etc) are correct & then proceeds to connect to the database. In your case, your credentials are wrong & you're getting the error message.